# Client credential flow, c# application closes when I use await to request the token

Tags: c#, azure-ad-msal

I'm expecting same result when I use await

```
// The following line of code closes the application abruptly.I also tried catching
// any exception by putting it in a try catch block but didn't 
//catch anyexception and got the same issue
var authNResult = await confidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] 
              {scope}).ExecuteAsync();


//But this works fine
var authNResult = confidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] 
              {scope}).ExecuteAsync().Result;


//this is the method 
public async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetAuthorizedHttpClient()
{
 IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClient =
                 ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientID)
                .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
                .WithAuthority(new Uri(Authority))
                .Build();

var authNResult = await confidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] 
                  {scope}).ExecuteAsync();

return authNresult;
}
```

I'm using this token to call an API on Azure. If I don't use await it gets the token and I'm able to call the API on Azure.

Comment: This should do it :    `var result = await confidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { scope }).ExecuteAsync()`

Comment: Are you using `async void`? Please post a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: I'm not using void and I've added the method. Please let me know if you need more information.